# Image not rendering right:0 on print layout

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I have a 1 page report that has a QR code image in it and I set it to be positioned absolute in print media.

in the web browser (Chrome & Edge) when I force render the print layout everything appears smooth and as expected

The issue happens when I run the print dialogue the QR Code image appears out of place

here is a screenshot of the web page with print render forced: as you can see its just like I want it

[image: screen shot with Print Render forced - QR code appears correct]

and here is the layout when I press Ctrl+P:(QR code out of place)
[image: Screen shot with Print Layout - QR code out of place]

here is the CSS code in print Media:

```
<style>
        @media print {
            .main-content {
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            h4 {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            @page {
                size: A4 portrait;
                margin-top: 3cm;
                margin-left: 1cm;
                margin-right: 1cm;
                margin-bottom: 8cm;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #qrcode {
                display: flex;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0cm;
                align-content: flex-end;
            }
            

            #isocode {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 16cm;
            }


            .noprint {
                display: none;
            }

            #myheader {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0.5cm;
                width: 100%;
                height: 3cm;
            }

            #myfooter {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0.5cm;
                height: 2.6cm;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .headerspace {
                height: 0cm;
            }

            .footerspace {
                height: 0cm;
            }



        }

        

        #isocodeimg {
            max-width: 70px;
            max-height: 70px;
        }

        .interestdiv {
            position: relative;
        }

        .interestlabel {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .interestlabel,
        .interestvalue {
            position: absolute;
        }

        p,
        span {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        br {
            display: block;
            /* makes it have a width */
            content: "";
            /* clears default height */
            margin-top: 8px;
            /* change this to whatever height you want it */
        }

        #canceldiv {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
            font-size: 5rem;
            color: red;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>
```

Here is also my full html code:

```
    <html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="utilities/style.css">
<link rel="icon" href="resources/ur.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uuid/8.1.0/uuidv4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/11.0.1/math.js" integrity="sha512-qUD6aWQY0c9uVWnPVcbUzQg9Q06qfCpZhOK7jbWDKEAuX+i6gwS5P2VoDe+ZghmUepiB1FtBY5gNosseexrt9Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="utilities/moment.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qrcodejs/1.0.0/qrcode.min.js" integrity="sha512-CNgIRecGo7nphbeZ04Sc13ka07paqdeTu0WR1IM4kNcpmBAUSHSQX0FslNhTDadL4O5SAGapGt4FodqL8My0mA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="utilities/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>

<script>
    function DiffYear(val) {
        /*let selectedDate = new Date(val);
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let diffInMs = currentDate - selectedDate;
        let diffInYears = diffInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);
        return diffInYears.toFixed(0);*/
        let selectedDate = moment(val.toString().padStart(4, '0'), 'YYYY');
    let currentDate = moment();
    let diffInYears = currentDate.diff(selectedDate, 'years');
    return diffInYears;
    }

    function DiffYearAge(val) {
      
      let selectedDate = new Date(val).getFullYear();
      let currentDate = new Date().getFullYear();
      let yearDifference = currentDate*1 - selectedDate*1;
    
    return yearDifference;
    }

    function DiffDay(date1, date2) {
        let diffInMilliseconds = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
        let diffInDays = Math.floor(diffInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return diffInDays;
    }

    function numberWithCommas(x, y) {
        x = x.toFixed(y);
        xabs = Math.abs(x);
        if (x < 0) {
            return "(" + xabs.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ")";
        } else {
            return xabs.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }


    }

    function validateEmail(inputId) {
  var emailInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
  

  // Regular expression for email validation
  var emailPattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;

  if (emailInput.value.trim() !== "") {
    if (!emailPattern.test(emailInput.value)) {
      //return false;
      alert("You must enter a valid email address!");
      emailInput.value = '';
    }
  }
  //return true;
}

function validatePhoneNumber(inputId) {
    var phoneInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
  // Regular expression for phone number validation with country code
  var phonePattern = /^\+\d{1,3}\d{3,}$/;

  if (phoneInput.value.trim() !== "") {
    if (!phonePattern.test(phoneInput.value)) {
      //return false;
      alert("You must enter a valid phone number like +9647501234567");
      phoneInput.value = '';
    }
  }

}

function TxtEnglishOnly(eleid) {
  if (isEnglish == 1) {
    let input = document.getElementById(eleid);
    let englishOnly = input.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/? ]/g, '');
    input.value = englishOnly;
  }
}

</script>

    <title>URIIC | POLICY VIEW</title>

    <style>
        @media print {
            .main-content {
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            h4 {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            @page {
                size: A4 portrait;
                margin-top: 3cm;
                margin-left: 1cm;
                margin-right: 1cm;
                margin-bottom: 8cm;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #qrcode {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 95% !important;
            }
            

            #isocode {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 16cm;
            }


            .noprint {
                display: none;
            }

            #myheader {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0.5cm;
                width: 100%;
                height: 3cm;
            }

            #myfooter {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0.5cm;
                height: 2.6cm;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .headerspace {
                height: 0cm;
            }

            .footerspace {
                height: 0cm;
            }



        }

        

        #isocodeimg {
            max-width: 70px;
            max-height: 70px;
        }

        .interestdiv {
            position: relative;
        }

        .interestlabel {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .interestlabel,
        .interestvalue {
            position: absolute;
        }

        p,
        span {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        br {
            display: block;
            /* makes it have a width */
            content: "";
            /* clears default height */
            margin-top: 8px;
            /* change this to whatever height you want it */
        }

        #canceldiv {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
            font-size: 5rem;
            color: red;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body class="print-page">
    <div class="text-center noprint">
        <br>
        <button onclick="window.print()"><i class="bi bi-printer"></i> Print</button>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="myheader">
            </div>
    <div id="canceldiv">
            </div>
    
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="headerspace"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="printables">
                        
                        <h4 class="text-center"><u>TRAVEL POLICY SCHEDULE</u></h4>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:4cm;">
                                <b><u>Policyholder</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                HUDA ELSAYED MAHMOUD ELSAYED BASYONY                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col">
                                <div id="qrcode" title="https://brokers.uriic.net/policychk.php?pid=4361761A-2543-4E13-8D1B-62B199AF108F"><canvas width="100" height="100" style="display: none;"></canvas><img style="display: block;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
                                <!--<div id="isocode">
                                    <img src="resources/iso.png" alt="..." id="isocodeimg">
                </div>-->
            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:4cm;">
                                <b><u>Address</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                IRAQ                            </div>

                            <div class="col"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:4cm;">
                                <b><u>Policy No.</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                03-23-0801-00237                            </div>
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:2.5cm;">
                                <b><u>Code</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                Abr alsharq for travel &amp; tourism                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:4cm;">
                                <b><u>Limit of Liability</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                EUR 30,000                            </div>
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:2.5cm;">
                                <b><u>Inception</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                21/10/2023                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:4cm;">
                                <b><u>Total Premium</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                As per attached invoice.                            </div>
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:2.5cm;">
                                <b><u>Expiry</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                19/11/2023                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:4cm;"></div>
                            <div class="col">
                                                            </div>
                            <div class="col" style="max-width:2.5cm;">
                                <b><u>Plan</u></b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                SCHENGEN/WORLDWIDE+ Covid-19                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-content">
                            <hr class="border border-dark border-1 opacity-75 my-1">
                            <div id="interestdiv" class="interestdiv" style="height: 140px;">
                                <div class="interestlabel" style="left:10px;
                                                                    top:30px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Date Of Birth</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:150px;
                                                                    top:30px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">08/09/1985</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:410px;
                                                                    top:30px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Age</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:550px;
                                                                    top:30px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">38</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:10px;
                                                                    top:50px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Gender</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:150px;
                                                                    top:50px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">Female</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:410px;
                                                                    top:70px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Nationality</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:550px;
                                                                    top:70px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">Egyptian</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:10px;
                                                                    top:70px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Passport No</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:150px;
                                                                    top:70px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">A27135186</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:10px;
                                                                    top:110px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Duration(Days)</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:150px;
                                                                    top:110px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">30</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:410px;
                                                                    top:50px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Destination </div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:550px;
                                                                    top:50px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">Italy</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:10px;
                                                                    top:90px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Email</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:150px;
                                                                    top:90px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">OPS@ABRALSHARQ-TRAVEL.COM</div><div class="interestlabel" style="left:410px;
                                                                    top:90px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:100px;">Phone</div><div class="interestvalue" style="left:550px;
                                                                    top:90px;
                                                                    Height:20px;
                                                                    width:250px;">+9647718009900</div>                            </div>
                            <hr class="border border-dark border-1 opacity-75 my-1">
                            <table class="table table-sm table-xsm">
                                <thead class="border-bottom border-dark">
                                    <tr><th>Applicable Covers</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Deductibles</th>
                                    <th class="text-end">Limit of Covers (EUR)</th>
                                </tr></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr><td>Medical Expenses and Hospitalization Abroad</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">30,000</td></tr><tr><td>Emergency Medical Evacuation</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">30,000</td></tr><tr><td>Medical Hospitalization Expenses Related to Covid-19/ 72 hours excess from arrival to destination</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">3,000</td></tr><tr><td>Emergenncy Medical Evacuation and Repatriation due to Covid-19 Treatment</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">2,500</td></tr><tr><td>Emergency Dental Care</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">1,000</td></tr><tr><td>Repatriation of Mortal Remains</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">5,000</td></tr><tr><td>Repatriation of Family Member Travelling with the Insured</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">2,000</td></tr><tr><td>Emergency Return Home Following Death of a Close Relative</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">2,000</td></tr><tr><td>Personal Assistance Services</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">0</td></tr><tr><td>24 Hours Assistance Services</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">0</td></tr><tr><td>Location and Forwarding of Personal Effects</td><td class="text-center"></td><td class="text-end">0</td></tr>                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <hr class="border border-dark border-1 opacity-75 my-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="clausesdiv">
                                        <p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;font-size:11px;">This policy covers only sudden illness and accidents. All Treatments related to or resulting from pre-existing medical conditions are excluded from this cover.</span></p><br><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;font-size:11px;">Except for the Covid-19 specific covers named above, all other covers become NIL if related to Covid-19. For a Covid-19 case to be admitted, the client should present a -ve test result done less than 72 hours from the trip departure time.</span></p><br><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;font-size:11px;">Claims must be reported within 48 hours from occurrence of the event and related original documents must be submitted to the company by the insured.</span></p><br><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#ff0000;">Policyholder of age 65 years old and above will pay 50% of the claim expenses.</span></p><p><span style="font-family:Arial (Arabic) sans-serif;font-size:15px;">بۆ دڵنیا بوون لە ماوەکانی تکایە سەردانی ئەم لینکەی خوارەوە بکە </span></p><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;font-size:14px;">للتأكد من صلاحية بوليصة التأمين، يرجى من حاملها الدخول على الرابط الأسفل</span></p><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;">In order to check this policy status visit this link: </span><span style="text-decoration:underline;font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;color:#0000ff;">&lt;https://brokers.uriic.net/check.php&gt;</span><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;"> or scan the above QR code.</span></p><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;">The insured person subject to losing all his rights under this policy, should contact the below number.</span></p><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;">(Please read carefully the general conditions).</span></p><p><span style="font-family:Tahoma sans-serif;">Please keep this letter of confirmation with you at all times.</span></p><p></p>                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr class="border border-dark border-1 opacity-75 my-1">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col text-center fw-bold">Issued in Duplicate in Company</div>
                                <div class="col text-center fw-bold">Date : 04/10/2023</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col text-center fw-bold">Policyholder / Insured</div>
                                <div class="col text-center fw-bold">For The Company</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col text-center"></div>
                                <div class="col text-center" id="uriicsign"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="footerspace"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div id="myfooter">
            </div>

<script>
    var qrtxt = "https://brokers.uriic.net/policychk.php?pid=4361761A-2543-4E13-8D1B-62B199AF108F";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var parentElement = $('#interestdiv');
        var maxHeight = 0;
        var minHeight = 1000000;
        // Iterate through all child elements and find the highest top value
        parentElement.children().each(function() {
            var childTop = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, childTop);
            minHeight = Math.min(minHeight, childTop);
        });
        // Set the height of the parent element to match the highest top value
        parentElement.height(maxHeight + minHeight);

        var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
            text: qrtxt,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            colorDark: "#000000",
            colorLight: "#ffffff",
            correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
        });


    });
</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Please have a closer look at: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Posting images doesn't count as a "reproducible example". Basically, we also need to see the HTML code.

Comment: I added the full html code in my page

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved

I only added Position: relative; styling to my body element